# How can I place the SELECTED elements from database into a variable

Tags: php, mysql

How can I place these elements into a variable?

```
$user_information = $connect->prepare("SELECT email, gender, firstname, middlename, FROM members");
```

like

```
$firstname = 'firstname';
$gender = 'gender';
$email = 'email';
```

how can I do this

Thanks in advance

Comment: you are using PDO or mysqli?

Comment: See [bind_result](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PDO

```
  $user_information ->execute();
  $result = $user_information->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $firstname = $result['firstname'];
  $gender = $result['gender'];
  $email = $result['email'];
```

if you are using mysqli

```
$user_information->execute();
$user_information->bind_result($firstname, $gender, $email);
$user_information->fetch();
printf("%s, %s, %s\n", $firstname, $gender, $email);
$user_information ->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP and PDO, you can use the in the fetch method to get an object using `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`. http://de3.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

```
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
print $result->NAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list($email, $gender, $firstname, $middlename) = $user_information;
```

For more info check [LIST function @ PHP docs](http://php.net/list).

Answer (score 0):

if it returns an object you can get it like;

```
$firstname = $user_information->firstname;
$gender = $user_information->gender;
$email = $user_information->email;
```

or if it returns an array;

```
$firstname = $user_information["firstname"];
$gender = $user_information["gender"];
$email = $user_information["email"];
```